# perl ping failure

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::Ping;
$p = Net::Ping->new();
my $main_ip="$ARGV[0]";

if ($p->ping($main_ip,1)){
    $result=true;
    print "$main_ip is alive \n";
}else{
    print "$main_ip is down \n";
}
```

I am using above perl script to ping check the server. It worked fine all the cases except for IP 192.168.0.168.

```
$ perl test.pl 192.168.0.168
```

192.168.0.168 is down

```
]$ ping 192.168.0.168

PING 192.168.0.168 (192.168.0.168) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.168: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.304 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.168: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.355 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.168: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=2.94 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.168: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.388 ms

--- 192.168.0.168 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3292ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.304/0.997/2.944/1.124 ms

]$ ping 192.168.0.18

PING 192.168.0.18 (192.168.0.18) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.181 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.181 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.181 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 192.168.0.18 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3292ms
pipe 3

]$ perl test.pl 192.168.0.18

192.168.0.18 is down
```

I had no clue even I have increase ping timeout but the results same

Comment: real reason may be in firewall on 192.168.0.168, as I described in my answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only problem i can think of is, that the ping command uses the ICMP protocol as default, while `Net::Ping` uses TCP. You can switch `Net::Ping` to ICMP by creating your object like this:

```
my $p = Net::Ping->new( 'icmp' );
```

Take note, that making ICMP pings requires root privilege on Unix.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. But need to find out the real reason.

Comment: If that worked, then the machine behind 192.168.0.168 does not answer to TCP pings or there is a firewall blocking the TCP ping. I doubt that the real problem lies with you program.

Answer (score 1):

In order to send icmp packets you must have rights to create raw sockets, i.e. have root rights.
I suppose you running ping.pl as ordinary user, but you need to be root

```
ls -al `which ping`
-rws--x--x 1 root root 39640 Dec 17  2011 /bin/ping
   ^
   |
   suid bit
```

ping program has a suid bit, which allows to run ping program with root rights.

By default Net::Ping tries to connect to `echo` port (7/tcp), if it gets ECONNREFUSED - this means that host is up but refuses connection (nothing is listening on that port). if connect breaks on timeout, this means that host is down.

But! I can block all connection to 7/tcp by firewall:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 7 -j DROP
```

and... voila, i get `down` instead of `alive`

So, you should check firewall on your `failure pinged` host

Comment: He wrote "It worked fine all the cases except for IP 192.168.0.168", so I guess that there must be some other exception. Besides, the `Net::Ping` module does not use the installed ping program. The docs (http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/Ping.html) say that the default protocol (tcp) does not require special privileges.